# Instagram Graph API getting users geolocation without login and access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I know that you want to suggest me private api or any **scraper**. I used them but they don`t return accounts geolocation. In my application I want to get instagram accounts geolocation, likes, comments, followers and follows in order to get engagement of account.

If you say it is not possible look [TrendHero](https://trendhero.io/) website it returns all information about users, followers rank, country information and other handy information which you can find in your insights (in instagram account) **without users permissions**.

Comment: Instagram only allows you to use their API. They don't allow you to scrape them. Just because some site does it doesn't mean it is allowed or will not break tomorrow for them.

Comment: @WizKid you are right and I know that instagram didn`t allowed them, but just think that how they get this information. And how this information is the same with my insights in instagram account.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression, without caring to dive deep into the company you linked, is they are simply using scrapers.  That's typically how those big contact databases are done.

The Instagram APIs simply don't provide the access they used to.  That's how it is. Simply asserting there must be a way doesn't mean there actually is.

@WizKid Instagram can't actually prevent scraping.  They just make a little fuss about it.